# Sticky top in bootstrap 5.3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5.3 and I used .sticky-top property for my navbar and side bar. for some horizontal overflow problem I added `html, body { max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }` to my CSS file and since then .sticky-top is not working.
anyone has any ideas what's the problem here?